# Unexpected behavior when adding UnitVector to vector (list)

Tags: list-manipulation

The expression

```
{v1,v2} + UnitVector[2,x]
```

evaluates to

```
{v1 + UnitVector[2, x], v2 + UnitVector[2, x]}
```

but that is suddenly a list of two lists with length 2. E.g. using

```
{v1 + UnitVector[2, x], v2 + UnitVector[2, x]} /. x->2
```

evaluates to

```
{{1 + v1, v1}, {1 + v2, v2}}.
```

But I expect to stay in two dimensions when I write

```
{v1,v2} + UnitVector[2,x]
```

because clearly `UnitVector[2,x]` is always a two dimensional vector.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I enforce somehow that this expression stays a two dimensional vector? I can see that lists aren't necessarily vectors but it still seems strange to me to treat the `UnitVector[2,x]` like a constant.

Comment: `UnitVector[n, k]` only becomes a vector when both `n` and `k` are positive integers and `k <= n`. Until then, it is undefined and gets treated like any other undefined symbol when added to a vector , e.g., `Clear[a]; {v1, v2} + a`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Is there a way to use it as a vector valued variable? Maybe not. It is probably not the Mathematica way. I now rewrote my code with explicit component-wise evaluation. It is just much more ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TranslationTransform[]` for this:

```
expr = TranslationTransform[UnitVector[2, k]][{v1, v2}];

expr /. k -> 1
   {1 + v1, v2}

expr /. k -> 2
   {v1, 1 + v2}
```

Comment: I don't think I would have found that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could e.g. define a function:

```
ClearAll[addUnit]
addUnit[vec_, x_Integer] := vec + UnitVector[x]
```

with this:

```
addUnit[{1, 1}, 1]
addUnit[{1, 1}, 2]

(* {2, 1}
{1, 2} *)
```

Alternatively you can as well define:

```
ClearAll[addUnit]
addUnit[vec_, 1] := vec + UnitVector[1]
addUnit[vec_, 2] := vec + UnitVector[2]
```